# FB.ui failing "Error Message: session key has no corresponding user"

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to open a facebook dialog, however for reasons that I don't understand yet it doesn't work.

This code did work:
(I cleaned it up a little bit to better illustrate the problem)

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  // get settings...
  $app_id = Drupal.settings.gdp_general.appid;
  $channel_url = Drupal.settings.gdp_general.channel_url;
  // init Facebook api
  FB.init({
    appId      : $app_id, // App ID
    channelURL : $channel_url, // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });
};

// login the user and ask for the required permissions.
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    // do some stuff with the retrieved data
    // ....
    // now post something on the users wall
    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {
      caption: $title,
      message: $description,
      link: $url
      }, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
      // error
      } else {
        // post was succesfull
        $form.submit();
      }
    });

  });
} else {
  //error
}
}, {scope: 'email, publish_stream'}); 
};
```

This post a message to the users wall, and works fine. 
However I think it would be nicer for the user to open a dialog so that he can see what will be posted to his wall.

But when I change

```
    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {
```

to

```
   FB.ui({method: 'feed',
```

It doesn't work anymore and facebook returns an error "Error Message: session key has no corresponding user".

Comment: I'm having this same issue if I try to use the access token of a test user and open an apprequests dialog - same error (iPhone)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Page Access Token / are logged in as a page? The dialogs won't work in that case

Comment: Could you please explain that? I would think that the FB.login function would provide the proper rights?